# The 'python' and 'pip' commands are not working in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal, but it works in an external terminal

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, terminal, environment-variables, command-prompt

I have configured my the python,pip path in environment variables. It works in an external terminal very well. But doesn't work in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal. How can I fix it?

Error message:

[image]

Comment: What error does it show in vs code? kindly elaborate.

Comment: It simply says "python/pip is not recognized as an internal or external command."

Comment: Check out this video it might fix the problem- https://youtu.be/dNFgRUD2w68

Comment: This might also solve your problem- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference

Comment: @sam2611 I have already tried the solutions you have mentioned but it didn't solve my problem :(

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68348870/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I face this same issue then What I do is I open the cmd where pip is working then I go to the exact path where python folder is in my system

> C :\Program Files\Python310

then I entered pip command-

```
**pip install discord**
```

and the error resolved automatically in VsCode..

You can go with another method if doesn't suit your style this work for me atleast.