# Things such as 'pip' work in a regular Windows terminal, but not in the Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm trying to install some packages for Python.

I've changed the terminal from PS to Terminal.

I've verified that I have the correct paths in the system variables.

I've verified that the aliases are turned off.

I'm still having issues.

If I go to start, and pull up cmd.exe and type "pip help" I get the help menu that I should. However, when I try and run it in the terminal in Visual Studio Code, I get

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What am I doing wrong here? I've checked a dozen different tutorials. I've completely uninstalled Visual Studio Code and the Python interpreter. I'm at a loss. What is wrong here?

I've tried the "solutions" offered here: *[The 'python' and 'pip' commands are not working in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal, but it works in an external terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348870/python-and-pip-command-not-working-in-vs-code-integrted-terminal-but-works-in-ex)*, but none of them worked.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment or a conda environment?

Comment: What is "PS"? [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? Is the actual text in the user interface *"Windows PowerShell"*?

Comment: I think you hit one of the low-scored duplicates. There are ***a lot*** of duplicates. There is also a canonical question somewhere, with a lot of high-quality answers.

Comment: A candidate: *[Visual Studio Code terminal is failing to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch?noredirect=1&lq=1)*. In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202834/visual-studio-code-terminal-is-failing-to-launch/63704415#63704415). Though there is probably an older better-scored one with more answers somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the compatibility in Visual Studio Code settings and set administrator permissions for Visual Studio Code.

[image]

Comment: Re *"modify the compatibility in Visual Studio Code settings"*: How exactly? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72863347/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
py -m pip help
```

Because I also had the same problem and it worked.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is it supposed to do? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73250096/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today). Thanks in advance.